# Jquery listen to non dom object change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which does change on user action continuously to keep track of the grid so i thought that if its possible to trigger an event as soon as the object changes?
I know this can be done but can we just not register an event on object and as soon as the object changes we can trigger the event which calls a function dealing with the state of object?

What i have came up with works but i have to manually trigger each time i change object can we just sit there and wait for object to change and act upon it ?

```
 $( requestProcessStatus ).trigger ("valueChanged"); // trigger this each time object changes` 

$( requestProcessStatus ).bind("valueChanged", function() {
console.log("object changed");
}); // do whatever in here 


 requestProcessStatus : {
    RequestNumber : '',
    ProcessStatus : '',
    LoanTrackingInfo : [
      LocalNumber: '',
      ProcessStatus: ''
    ]
},
```

I have this object and as soon as user enters the LocalNumber in textbox i fire up `ajax` request and if the response is successful the LoantrackingInfo array gets populated with LocalNumber and the proccessStatus= Success and it can scale upto infinite. As soon as the object changes i want to reflect those changes in my grid which displays all the localnumber and its corresponding status in grid?

So is it possible to just listen to the object change event ?

Comment: *"can we just sit there and wait for object to change and act upon it ?"* Yes, but it would be VERY inefficient, you're best off doing what you're already doing.

Comment: "So is it possible / to just listen to the object / change event ?" isn't that a haïku ? :)

Comment: That's the way to go. If you want a more readable/uncluttered approach, pick a framework like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: @KevinB inefficient in what ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the "set + trigger" inside a method :

```
requestProcessStatus.setVal = function( attr, value ){
   this[attr] = value;
   $(this).trigger('valueChanged');
}
```

Obviously, you will have the responsibility to only modify the object through this method if you want the event to always trigger ...

Comment: I like the idea of calling trigger and setting value in one place +1

Answer (score 0):

> "can we just sit there and wait for object to change and act upon it
>   ?"

Yes, but it would be VERY inefficient, you're best off doing what you're already doing.

This is how you would do it though:

```
previousObjectState = {};
function checkForChanges () {
    // iterate over object looking for changes
    if (changes happened) {
        $(theObject).trigger("change");
    }
    previousObjectState = $.extend(true,{},theObject);
}

setInterval(checkForChanges,100);
```

It would have to parse and look for changes every n ms, which can be very expensive.

Comment: Thats not i would go with ,i think i can carry on what i am doing if this is the case .. Thanks Kevin +1 for your suggestion