# jQuery update DOM on JSON Object Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have the following JSON Object:

```
let myObject = [
    { title: 'exampleTitle1', content: 'exampleContent1'}
    { title: 'exampleTitle2', content: 'exampleContent2'}
]
```

Furthermore in my code, let's say I'm appending the titles to an Unordered List as follows:

```
myObject.forEach(function(container){
    $('ul').append('<li>' + container.content + '</li>');
})
```

Everything is fine up to this point, but later in my code, I wanna be able to do something like:

```
 myObject[0].content = "New Content"
```

And get the DOM to update with the changed Object.
How should I go for this without using anything like Vue or React.
Is there a way for me to listen for an object change?

Comment: This has been answered elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275640/jquery-listen-to-non-dom-object-change-event -- basically, you are likely going to want to wrap that JSON object in another object, that simply monitors it for changes and, in the event that a field is changed, you trigger a custom event. Then you can simply listen for that event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery listen to non dom object change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275640/jquery-listen-to-non-dom-object-change-event)

Answer (score 0):

using Object.defineProperty to redefine content property , in the set function, trigger "Change.content.myObj" event , then you can refresh UI in the event handler.
holp this helpful.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {   
        myObject.forEach(function (container) {
            var li = $('ul').append('<li id="' + container.title + '">' + container.content + '</li>');
        })
        $(document).on("Change.content.myObj", function (e, item) {
            $("#" + item.title).text(item.content);
        })
     });

     let myObject = [
        { title: 'exampleTitle1', content: 'exampleContent1'},
        { title: 'exampleTitle2', content: 'exampleContent2'}
     ]

     myObject.forEach(item => {
         item._content = item.content;
         Object.defineProperty(item,'content', {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            get: function() {
                    return item._content;
                },
             set: function (value) {
                 item._content = value;
                 $(document).trigger("Change.content.myObj", item);
            }
        });
     });

     function changeContent() {
         myObject.forEach(item => item.content += "_1");
     }
</script>
<button onclick="changeContent();">changeContent</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good tutorial [here](https://davidwalsh.name/watch-object-changes) about how to do this. First of all make this code:

```
myObject.forEach(function(container){
    $('ul').append('<li>' + container.content + '</li>');
})
```

Into a function:

```
function displayItems() {
    myObject.forEach(function(container){
        $('ul').append('<li>' + container.content + '</li>');
    })
}
```

Then add a script from a new file:

```
<script src="change.js"></script>
```

And in change.js, add this code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (object, onChange) => { 
    const handler = {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        try {
            return new Proxy(target[property], handler);
    } catch (err) {
                return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
    }
    },
        defineProperty(target, property, descriptor) {
        onChange();
    return Reflect.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor);
    },
    deleteProperty(target, property) {
    onChange();
    return Reflect.deleteProperty(target, property);
    }
    };
return new Proxy(object, handler);
};
```

Then attach your object to this:

```
var myObjectRef = onChange(myObject, displayItems);
```

## Important

### to get the change detection working, you will now have to modify myObjectRef instead of myObject. Make sure you do this!

And now your code should all be working! Hopefully this helps!